# My spring bean not working properly?

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I'm getting null values for some of the methods in pojo class and other methods are working fine.
This is my POJO class Student.java

```
public class Student {
private int id;
private String name;
private String message1;
private String message2;
private String message3;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void init()
{
    System.out.println("Bean is started");
}

public void destroy()
{
    System.out.println("Bean is destroyed");
}
public String getMessage1() {
    return message1;
}
public void setMessage1(String message1) {
    this.message1 = message1;
}
public String getMessage2() {
    return message2;
}
public void setMessage2(String message2) {
    this.message2 = message2;
}
public String getMessage3() {
    return message3;
}
public void setMessage3(String message3) {
    this.message3 = message3;
}
}
```

This is my xml file, beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="student" class="Student">
    <property name="id" value="2342"></property>
    <property name="name" value="RamaKrishna"></property>
    <property name="message1" value="Student--message1"></property>
    <property name="message3" value="Student--message3"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

This is my main method logic, Logic.java

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class Logic{
public static void main(String args[]){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

    Student student = (Student)context.getBean("student");

    System.out.println(student.getId());
    System.out.println(student.getName());
    System.out.println(student.getMessage1());
    System.out.println(student.getMessage3());
}
}
```

I'm getting output null values for the 3rd and 4th print statements.
My output is :

```
2342
RamaKrishna
null
null
```

I supposed to get output like

```
2342
RamaKrishna
Student--message1
Student--message3
```

Please help to understand why it is giving like this.

Answer (score -1):

Your code work fine. My output:

```
2342
RamaKrishna
Student--message1
Student--message3
```

Try recompile your code

Comment: When i commented the third and fourth property output became

2342
RamaKrishna
null
null

But if I uncomment it works fine.